# How to install Gcc on Fedora 13 with i686 Architecture!

Tags: linux, fedora, gcc

I have installed Fedora 13 lately,
however its architecture is i686...
i want to install the GNU C Compiler (both c and c++).....
now i searched for i686 architecture gcc but most of them are not compiled..
and are archives e.g., gcc-4.4.1.tar.....
Also, some RPMs say about dependencies. Is there a simpler solution?

Can anyone help me with this? How to install Gcc, please bear in mind that i dont have any compiler in Fedora even cc is not there!! 
I installed fedora from a live cd i got with the Digit Magazine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yum install gcc gcc-c++
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Fedora's package manager to install gcc. It will automatically get the right packages for you.

Installing packages is explained e.g. here:

http://www.tuxmagazine.com/node/1000038/print

If you installed from a CD, you may have to add other sources for packages, so the package manager knows where to download packages from. This is also explained in the article.